# Sqlite: How to split a column by delimiter and order by split count result without excluding duplicates

Tags: android, sqlite, split

I'm trying to do a simple select where the returned rows are order by the result of a split count result.

Table example:

[image]

According to the image, If I were to split by comma and order by count result of this split, at an ascending order, it would go something like this:

> T1, T2, T3
>
> T1, T2
>
> T1
>
> T3
>
> T2

I've tried this query:

```
Select SomeCol FROM Table GROUP BY SomeCol Order BY Count(instr(SomeCol, ',')) ASC
```

This works if there isn't duplicity, but it needs to work if there is duplicity. It should be able to display duplicate rows ordered by the split count.

Comment: What will happen if you remove the group by

Comment: I get this error `misuse of aggregate: count()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read some similar solutions and came up with one based on the ones I read.

```
Select SomeCol FROM Table Order BY length( replace(SomeCol , ',', '') ) ASC
```